# Graphing Directed Motion in Labview

Tags: graph, labview

I was wondering if it was possible to graph directed motion in Labview. That is, I am trying to graph the motion of the top of a joystick and the direction it is moving in, perhaps with an arrow.

Thank you in advance for any help on the matter.

Comment: As in an x-y coordinate on a 2D graph to show its position and a vector to indicate its velocity?

Comment: Well it doesnt need to show its velocity, just direction it is travelling in, on the same graph as position.

Comment: And which part of the problem is giving you trouble?  How far have you gotten?  Do you have the velocity and position data already?  Just the graphing component?  Which version of LabView?

Comment: http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/2D-Vector-Plot/td-p/192478

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not absolutely sure if this is what you asked for. However this is how I would graph something with arrows:

**Code as screenshot:**

Block diagram

[image: Block diagram]

Front panel

[image: Front panel]

**Code explained in text form:**

- The front panel consists of a "2D Compass" graph which can be found under Modern/Graph/Compass Plot
- To create the data for the plot I have used two double array constants. One for the angles of the arrows and the other one for their length. These two constants are connected to the Plot Helper vi which gets automatically inserted and connected with the plot indicator.

Comment: Yes sure that is right. However it is difficult to post LabView code without images and I am not yet allowed to post inline images.